# IIS executable not executing

Tags: iis, ssis, executable

I have been looking at an issue for a week straight and have been unable to figure it out and I am *desperate* for the fix.

On a client site, we have two environments: UAT and PROD.  UAT works perfect (Please keep this in mind).  We are now trying to deploy the solution to PROD but certain parts of the solution are not working.

We have developed an asp.net application that we provide to clients to allow them to invoke SSIS packages (there are a couple of drop downs that they first select then click a button named "invoke").
When the user clicks the Invoke button, a batch file named InvokeSSIS.bat is called that assembles a command line call to dtexec with the appropriate parameters.

I'm having a problem with a particular package that is responsible for calling an executable which generates a spreadsheet that i will be importing into my system.

The executable is on an mapped H:\ drive.

I have modified the InvokeSSIS.bat batch file to capture the command the batch file is generating.  If I execute this command from the command line, it works perfectly.  From the webapp Invoker, it executes the package but the tasks responsible for calling the executable doesn't execute as the entire package takes only 1 second to complete (whereas it should take about a minute.)

The executable DOES have a GUI, but it is NOT interactive. This is because when you call the GUI with specific parameters, it automatically runs in batch mode and executes a macro used to generate the desired spreadsheet.

I know this is ok because it works on the UAT server AND it works from the command line!

I have checked the permissions on the executable (bu right-clicking the executable and clicking properties.)  I have granted Full Control on the executable to the same user specified as the identity tab of the application pool i am using.

Can someone please help me?  As I said I am dying over here!

Please let me know if you have any ideas or what other info you need.

Environment (both UAT and PROD)
OS: Windows Server 2003
IIS 6
asp.net 2.0
SQL Server 2008

Thanks!

Steve

Comment: Could you modify your post to clearly lay out what calls/executes what, where, and when exactly? Your post makes it very difficult to figure out. Also, it's a bad idea to give the IIS worker process *full* rights to an executable, and it's not needed in any case.

Comment: And your IIS App pool identities are different in UAT/PRD?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a mapped drive with IIS.

You must use the \\servername syntax to reach files on other systems.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with user544284 that this is at least in part a mapping issue.  I'll ignore for a minute the complete insanity of having a web application call a batch file to start an executable that's on a remote network drive through a drive letter mapping.

Most likely the UAT box has something set up that maps that drive letter for you which Prod is missing.

The only other possibility is a security violation is occurring.  Running .exe's from a network drive is generally frowned on.  Do the two environments have the exact same version of windows?  Are they configured the same with regards to UAC?  Any differences here are going to be important.

Which brings up an interesting thought.  I wonder if someone logged in to the UAT server using the same account credentials the app pool is using and added the ip address of the machine where the exe lives to the list of "Local Intranet" sites...  Or, if they installed SSIS on the UAT server itself.

Just because YOU can log in to the server and run it on the command line means nothing.  You have to find out if the drive letter is mapped at all for the user that the web app is running under and whether that user has the required security bits and whether the local OS will allow it regardless.

Okay, I can't ignore it: hairbrained is the nicest adjective I can come up with for this "architecture".  Do yourself a favor and go back to the drawing board on this one.  It has the word "brittle" written all over it, as you have already found.  Instead of building out a batch file to call dtexec, just do it directly either by something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CallSSISFromCSharp.aspx?df=100&forumid=309846&exp=0&select=1518271) or [this](http://forums.asp.net/p/1149972/1873190.aspx#1873190).

Comment: +1 for identifying the "architecture" as the cause; the problem as the symptom.  Otherwise we are just a bunch of low-level responders with no serious effect.